# Fast and Parallel algorithm for A*A^T, where A is a sparse 0-1 Matrix

Tags: sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Given A is a large, sparse, 0-1 matrix, (not necessarily a square matrix). I want to calculate `B = A*A^T`, where `A^T` is the transpose of `A`. Note that although A is 0-1 matrix, B is not 0-1 matrix.

In addition, this question has the following special features:

1. I don't need the elements on the diagonal of `B`, so it's okay to either delete them after calculation or ignore them when calculating.
2. I only need to know the values of all non-zero elements in `B` (except for the elements on the diagonal), so it is OK if the program only gives a list which contains all non-zero elements. However, repeated elements cannot be merged: For example, if `B[2,3] = B[2,4] = 1`, then this list should contain two '1's instead of one.
3. Since `B` must be a symmetric matrix, it is also possible to give only the upper or lower part of it.

I have tried using Eigen (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/). But the functions of sparse matrix in Eigen are not specifically optimized for this problem, I hope to get some more efficient algorithms.

Any algorithm, open source library, or papers are welcome.

Related Questions:
[Which is the best way to multiply a large and sparse matrix with its transpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566633/which-is-the-best-way-to-multiply-a-large-and-sparse-matrix-with-its-transpose)

[sparse sparse product A^T*A optim in Eigen lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784501/sparse-sparse-product-ata-optim-in-eigen-lib)

Comment: Maybe [cs.se] would be more suitable for general algorithm questions?

Comment: I guess the answer heavily depends on the storage schemes of `A` and `B` and their sizes. The method of "Four Russians" can be of some help here.

Comment: CHOLMOD has a function for this, `cholmod_aat`. But it seems like this should be easy: it's a bunch of set-intersections between sparse sets, counting only the cardinality.

Comment: How sparse is `A`? Density?

Comment: There's also a site on stackexchange.com that's dedicated to maths. Since you don't ask a programming question, assigning two conflicting (read the descriptions!) tags with C and C++ doesn't help either, I just removed them. As a new user here, please make sure you take the [tour] and read [ask].