# sparse matrix multiplication with python

Tags: python, matrix, multiplication, sparse-matrix

I wonder how to do matrix multiplication if one of the matrices is sparse.
the mul(A,B) command does not support sparse matrices as far as I know, Should I write my own routine ?

A  sparse matrix such as lil_matrix
B  full matrix, any regular matrix or ndarray.

C = A*B , * being matrix multiplication ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matrix multiplication for sparse matrices in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477733/matrix-multiplication-for-sparse-matrices-in-python)

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not the same as element wise multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at module scipy.sparse. I think it should get the job done fairly quickly. Obviously you would need the Scipy and numpy library for this though.

For More info please read the following answer: [Matrix multiplication for sparse matrices in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477733/matrix-multiplication-for-sparse-matrices-in-python)